# Progress in FTP file upload with WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, events, ftp, webclient

I have the following code that works - uploads the file, but neither progress nor completion events are fired. Any ideas why?

```
try
{
    string srcFilePath = @"C:\Projects\MySetup.zip";
    string url = "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/downloads/MySetup.zip";

    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "pass");

    client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged; 
                
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, srcFilePath);
}
catch(System.Net.WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ": " + e.Status);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

private static void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Percent complete: {0}", e.ProgressPercentage));
}

private static void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    doneEvent.Set();
}
```

I tried the above code and expected that the event will fire and will provide feedback about completion and progress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are using `UploadFileAsync` method to upload a file to the server. However, since it is an upload operation, the `DownloadProgressChanged` and `DownloadFileCompleted` events will not be fired because they are designed for tracking download operations.

You should use [`WebClient.UploadProgressChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged) event instead of `DownloadProgressChanged` and [`WebClient.UploadFileCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted) event instead of `DownloadFileCompleted`. This events are specifically designed for tracking upload progress:

```
client.UploadFileCompleted += Client_UploadFileCompleted;
client.UploadProgressChanged += Client_UploadProgressChanged; 

...
private static void Client_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Percent complete: {0}", e.ProgressPercentage));
}

private static void Client_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    doneEvent.Set();
}
```

> `UploadFileCompleted` is raised each time an asynchronous file upload operation completes. Asynchronous file uploads are started by calling the `UploadFileAsync` methods.

> `UploadProgressChanged`  is raised each time an asynchronous upload makes progress. This event is raised when uploads are started using any of the following methods: `UploadDataAsync`, `UploadFileAsync`, `UploadValuesAsync`.

Comment: Oops! Stupid me ;-)